# No spinner at loading new page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I use the new version of jquery mobile (1.4.3) and I have a lot of different html files. I'm linking to them with a navigation. If I click on a link the page is loaded but there is no loading spinner and a short blink/flickering until the page appears.

In the jsfiddle I create a multi page, but the issue looks the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/knobli/yh7guzvu/1/

```
<body>
    <div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" data-theme="b">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-theme="a" id="navigation">
            <li><a href="#trainings">Training</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /panel -->
    <div data-role="page" id="mainpage">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                <h1>News</h1>
    <a href="#left-panel" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" class="ui-nodisc-icon">Open left panel</a>
    <a href="settings.html" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" class="ui-nodisc-icon">Settings</a>

        </div>
        <!-- /header -->
        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-ajax="true" data-inset="false" id="newsList"></ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /content -->
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="trainings" data-url="trainings">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                <h1>Trainings</h1>
    <a href="#left-panel" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" class="ui-nodisc-icon">Open left panel</a>
    <a href="settings.html" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" class="ui-nodisc-icon">Settings</a>

        </div>
        <!-- /header -->
        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-ajax="true" data-inset="false" id="newsList">
                <li>Test</li>
                <li>Test</li>
                <li>Test</li>
                <li>Test</li>
                <li>Test</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /content -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Not sure if you are supposed to see a spinner. I dont see it in my pages either. You can show  it manually. -- http://jsfiddle.net/eo8n2Lz5/  -- and hide it like this ---   ($.mobile.loading("hide");)

Comment: @Tasos thanks, that's also my solution, I add it manually (ajaxSetup: beforeSend) and remove it after loading (ajaxSetup: complete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the fading transition effect you can set the transition effect to 'none' by adding 
`data-transition="none"` to your a hrefs.
Another option is to set the default transition effect for pagechanges:

```
$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
```

See your example without effects: http://jsfiddle.net/klickagent/s0bwnsxa/1/

Comment: Thanks, but there is also a problem with the inexisting load spinner